# How to use PHP class throughout application without affecting much overhead performance

Tags: php

So, I have this class that gets used over and over again throughout my app. This is just an example, not what's actually needed to be done:

File A:

```
class Names {

  public function first() {
    echo 'Bob';
  }

}
```

That file is autoloaded into my app using `spl_autoload_register` and used all throughout in other pages/classes:

File B:

```
class LastNames {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->first = new Names();
  }

  public function last() {
    echo $this->first->first().' Smith';
  }

}

$names = new LastNames();

echo $names->last(); // Bob Smith
```

I have many files that instantiate the class `Names` inside the constructor.

- Does this cause much of a hit on performance?
- Should I be using `static function` instead of `public function`?
- Is there a better way to reuse the functions inside `Names` over and over again inside different classes?

Comment: define "much" re performance. You only need static (as far as I'm aware) if you want a single instance rather than a modular instance of a class method (function), specific to each class object. I *think* this is typically referenced as Abstracts.

Comment: `inside the constructor` go and inject teh instance instead of creating it in the function. `__construct(Names $names)` Topic: dependency injection

Comment: Instantiating objects is par for the course. You can't avoid instantiating an object if that is what your business logic requires. Even instantiating "many" small objects is not typically a problem. The question is: **Is it a problem for you?** Have you tested it? Have you found issues? Issues that actually need addressing in the real world, otherwise your code would be infeasible? Unless and until you actually encounter performance issues, simply do not worry about them. Instantiate your objects, done.

Comment: Do you have performance issues? If not, don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to instantiate the object only once and then **dependency inject** it everywhere it's needed. That really depends on how this is supposed to be used, which we have insufficient information about.

Comment: Does your code use a database? This is where you should worry about performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, using static function is one of them :

```
class LastNames {   
    public static function foo(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or you can use a singleton :

```
class LastNames {
   private static $instance = null;

   private function __construct(){
      // do stuff
   }

   public function foo(){
      // do stuff
   }

   public static function getInstance(){

      if ( !self::$instance ){
          self::$instance = new LastNames();
      }

      return self::$instance;

   }

}
```

And then you can call it with :

```
$lastnames = LastNames::getInstance();
$lastnames->foo();
```

Comment: `constructor` should be **private**. @JROB here the performance [https://3v4l.org/Adcq6](https://3v4l.org/Adcq6)

Comment: You are right, I edited.

Comment: It does not appear to me that a singleton/static class would be an appropriate solution here, as that greatly changes the class' behaviour.